# Реализация кросспостинга с веб сайта в соц сети

Tags: wordpress, соцсети

Задача, реализовать кросспостинг новостей, с сайта, в соце сети, а именно в группы (facebook, vk, odnoklassniki) (Эта задача пока что для меня самая важная) а главное что бы постинг был полноценным

Заголовок + превью новости + изображение (изображение очень важно что бы было), так как стандартными средствами самих соц сетей, оно все равно не отображаеться.

Т.е логика примерна такая

```
Сайт Компании -> Facebook Group > Ok Group > Vk Group
```

Думаю как правильно это все реализовать без посторонних напичканых плагинов ? может есть где то куски кодов api с примерами и обьяснениями ?

Нужен ваш совет, как лучше это сделать, так как писать новости, в каждую соц сеть это очень рутинная работа. А так получается у нас есть сайт компании, который выступает в качестве донора новостей для всех остальных наших соц площадок. (Стронние сервисы тоже нет желание использовать)

Сайт компании на платформе Wordpress

Comment: Плагин Next Scripts: Social Networks Auto Poster, решающий эту задачу, содержит 17640 строк на php, плюс js и css. Несколько лет эксплуатации показали, что периодически публикация перестает работать и возобновляется после обновления плагина, что говорит о том, что API сетей постоянно меняется. Вам предлагается повторить этот подвиг с написанием подобного кода и постоянно его поддерживать. Восход солнца вручную, так сказать.

Comment: Да, читал я о подобном плагине, но там вроде нет, картинок. (Как я видел в примерах). Что на счет API, то оно не так часто меняеться, и всегда лучше разрабатывать такие вещи самому, так как потом их можно подстроить под себя, всякие плюшки и т д. А разбираться в чужом коде + там напичканно для всех соц сетей, а мне нужно три основных. Т.е Цель, сделать свое, по минимуму (что требуеться) и потом уже в будущем отталкиваться от данной наработки.

Comment: 1. Картинки он прекрасно публикует. Могу показать соцсети и основной сайт. 2. Разрабатывать-то можно, но трудозатраты превысят всякие разумные пределы. Не забывайте, кроме самого подключения, вам придется дать и интерфейс пользователю с настройками, иначе это будет очередной пример бомбы замедленного действия, когда пользователь за любым чихом должен будет обращаться к девелоперу и платить, платить... 3. Как показала практика, API обновляется стабильно раз в 3-4 месяца.

Comment: 4. Не думаю, что 20 соцсетей в в 7 раз больше кода, чем 3 основных. Оцениваю увеличение кода с 3 до 20 сетей в 25%. Таким образом, вам придется написать 12 тысяч строк кода, чтобы это был нормальный продукт.

Comment: Не знаю как вы там оцениваете, но мне нужен минимальный подход к делу, что бы выполняло то что нужно и ничего лишнего. Сейчас читаю документацию по API. Если взять в общем, то вроде ничего сложного, но как на практике будет пока не знаю. Еще дело в том, что нужно будет интегрировать эти скрипты, наверно ввиде плагина а не вшивать их в сам wp. К примеру когда мы постим новость (переменные подставлялись так же в скрипт который будет отсылать данные в соц сеть) и по ответу определять успех публикации. Дело даже не в кол-ве кода, а в том что управляешь всем ты. И знаешь что как и где.

Comment: Ну вот именно, как на практике. А на практике все это будет усеяно граблями по полной программе. Ты всем управляешь всегда, если у тебя есть нормальный отладчик. Не, ну дерзайте, я ж не против )) Только при минимальных подходах часто случается ... эээ ... странный код, который потом невозможно ни модифицировать, ни поддерживать. А уж от фразы "вшивать в wp" меня совсем бросает в дрожь))) Вы имеете ввиду модификацию кода WordPress?

Comment: Ага :) но этому не быть, так как имел уже подобный первоначальный опыт по вшиванию, а потом разгребанию, возникших проблем, ну как ни как опыт учит. Было давно. Сейчас только ввиде плагинов без затрагивание ядра и прочих важностей. Поймите, суть того же плагина выше, такая же как и моя, но моя на много будет короче и проще, так как половину решений делает API и простой инклюд библиотек (как я понял). Как я понял главное получить ключи доступа, указать группу, а потом "твори" все что хочешь. Костыли делать не буду, все будет по стандарту из документаций, с минимум кода. + Опыт будет в работе

Comment: Нашел более простое решение, но не знаю пока что о подводных камнях. Вобщем постинг в группы производиться с помощью авторизации черезе CURL, т.е суть в том, что мы логинимся через CURL, постим активную ссылку, а как вы знаете соц сети, подгружают картинки сами, при постинге активных ссылок. То получается почти то что нужно Заголовок + Привьюшка